# case-insensitive import collision: "github.com/sirupsen/logrus" and "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus"

Tags: go

I'm working with ory-am / hydra and it makes me bug in the Golang library gopkg.in/gorethink/gorethink.v3, the error is as follows:

```
../../../gopkg.in/gorethink/gorethink.v3/cluster.go:10:2: case-insensitive import collision: "github.com/sirupsen/logrus" and "github.com/Sirupsen/ logrus "
```

this after adding go app.go

If you have any suggestions with which you can guide me to solve this incident

Answer (score 5):

That package went through a very painful, and regretful, rename some time back. It was previously `Sirupsen/logrus`, and was renamed to `sirupsen/logrus`. The latter is erroneously considered more idiomatic by some, but Go handles mixed case imports with no problem, so the rename was unnecessary, and the author [regrets it](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus/issues/570#issuecomment-313933276). But renaming back would just add to the confusion, so the decision was made to stick with the unnecessary lowercase version.

But that's all in the past. At this point, the lowercase version is the *only working one*.

The behavior you have observed is usually the result of importing two (or more) packages which depend on the `logrus` package, one depending on the older name, the other depending on the newer name.  Therefore, if you have a dependency that still has the upper-case version as a dependency, that library needs to be updated.

From the [project readme](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus#case-sensitivity):

> #### Case-sensitivity
>
> The organization's name was changed to lower-case--and this will not be changed back. If you are getting import conflicts due to case sensitivity, please use the lower-case import: github.com/sirupsen/logrus.

Alternately, you could vendor an old version of the library with the capitalized import name and update all of your imports to use that version.